# Reveal image and glow with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, gsap

I'm looking to do something like this in CSS/js

https://youtu.be/HLJldmEw3q8

I've looked at javascript animation frameworks like gsap and tried to figure out how to simply reveal an image while making the revealing edge glow and I'm at a loss. I suppose I can use the same technique to reveal the glowing arch too.

Any help or pointers for what I should search for or what techniques I should use would be a huge help. I'm completely new to this space.

Comment: I think the best method would involve animation a clip-path to reveil the image from top to bottom, here is something to get you started: https://css-tricks.com/animating-with-clip-path/

Comment: That's a great resource! Thanks for sharing

Comment: SVG + mask + gradients would be one of the better ways to do this sort of thing. This question is way too broad for StackOverflow though.

Answer (score -2):

this is actually not an answer. It's just my opinion.

First, I can say, animation in CSS/JS world is one of the hardest part ever, because of both visual effect and technical solution also.

With the same visual effect, we can have a lot of technical solution, with vary of ways to do. But you need tons of things to achieve. For example, you may split the image into smaller pieces, and write your custom CSS, write your custom Javascript code to display each parts. And that will take hours even days to deep dive into detail. Other than that, you need to aware about browser support for those your custom CSS. And after all, you should care more about the performance when calculating the position, color, etc in Javascript code.

I totally have not mentioned about the other things like where will you place that component with that animation into. For example, it should be easy when your page has only that logo. But the story will become complicated for example if you want to have dark mode. And then, you need to integrate all that pieces into `React`, `Vue` or `Angular`. It's totally a new story.

Let's talk about the animation libraries. There are so many libraries maybe can help you, but just maybe. Because all of them are supposed to be supported for very basic animations. For a more complex animation with no clear shape in visual, you will go back to write your custom script.

Back the your question, maybe you need to write your custom code to do something like:

- Show your image from to to down.
- After that, draw a circle with glow and calculate the correct time also.
- Do hundreds of time two steps above until you're happy with the behavior.

Again, animation is never be a easy problem.

Comment: Most of this is just rambling... The bullet points are the only part that come close to an answer.